# About a field extension and its normal closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Is the extension $K=\mathbb Q(\root5\of2)$ over the rationals normal? If not find its normal closure.

I know that K is not normal but I can not show and I think normal closure of $K$ is $Q(\root5\of2, i)$ is it true? and how can I show it is not normal?

Comment: If the extension were normal, it would contain all of the roots of the polynomial $x^5-2$. What are all $5$ roots for this polynomial, though? This will also give you what the normal closure ought to be in this case.

Comment: Your field $K$ contains one of the zeros of $p(x)=x^5-2$, This polynomial is irreducible (Eisenstein), so the normal closure should contain all the zeros of $p(x)$. Among them $\root5\of2\zeta$, where
$$\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}=\cos\frac{2\pi}5+i\sin\frac{2\pi}5.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think that $Q(\root5\of2,i)$ is normal extension

Comment: No, it is not. For the listed reason. $\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2,i)$ on the other hand would a be a normal extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ as the splitting field of $x^4-2$. The term $x^4$ means that the ratio of two zeros is a fourth root of unity, i.e. a power of $i$. Here the ratio of two zeros can be any power of $\zeta$